# Don't show null values in SELECT and GET of node-postgres

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, express, node-postgres

In my Express API, I want the client to be able to either include their phone number or website address or not include it at all.

This is how the SELECT statements are done:

```
-- SELECT all users
SELECT * FROM users
ORDER BY user_id ASC;

-- SELECT a user
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE user_id = $1;
```

This is how the INSERT statement is currently done which defaults any undefined value to `NULL`:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, username, email, phone, website)
VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *;
```

This is how the callback function of the POST request is handled:

```
const createUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, username, email, phone, website } = req.body;

  try {
    const create = await db.query(insertUser, [
      name,
      username,
      email,
      phone,
      website,
    ]);
    res
      .status(201)
      .json({ message: "User Created Successfully!", user: create.rows[0] });
  } catch (err) {
    // If UNIQUE constraint is violated
    if (err.code == "23505") {
      uniqueConstraintError(err, next);
    } else {
      serverError(err, next);
    }
  }
};
```

*`insertUser` is the variable that the PostgreSQL statement is stored in*.

If I try to add the user's info without entering phone and website (which are optional), the GET requests will still show those columns with the assigned value of `NULL`:

```
{
   "user_id": 10,
   "name": "Bruce Wayne",
   "username": "Batman",
   "email": "bat@cave.com",
   "phone": null,
   "website": null
}
```

**Is there any way to not show those `NULL` values in the SELECT statements and GET something like this instead?**

```
{
   "user_id": 10,
   "name": "Bruce Wayne",
   "username": "Batman",
   "email": "bat@cave.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use json_strip_nulls in postgres